# JavaScript: Movement in any direction and of any size in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, oop

I am wanting to create an array access function like a ticker tape. It can move in any direction looping around until it gets to the new value.

I am new to JS. I have come up with this solution but it feels horrible. I wonder if anyone has a better solution.

```
 var pet = ['dog', 'cat', 'rat', 'horse', 'mouse'];

 function loop(posChange, array) {
   if (isNaN(array.lp)) {
     array.lp = 0;
   };
   var newPos = array.lp + posChange;
     array.lp = (array.length + newPos) % array.length;
   return array[array.lp];
 };

 loop(2, pet);
```

**Edit:**(removed redundant if statements). For the sake clarity, imagine a music player with 5 songs that loop. I want to go forward 3 songs, get the result, forward another 2 and then back 1. Is this the best way of doing this?

```
var song = ['songa', 'songb', 'songc', 'songd', 'songe'];

function loop(posChange, array) {
   if (isNaN(array.lp)) {
     array.lp = 0;
   };
   var newPos = array.lp + posChange;
     array.lp = (array.length + newPos) % array.length;
   return array[array.lp];
 };

 loop(3, song);
 loop(2, song);
 loop(-1, song);
```

Comment: What do you intend to use the looping for? I don't think I've ever needed it for anything.

Comment: note that `array.lp = (array.length + newPos) % array.length;` will work the same in any of your three cases.

Comment: `array.push(arr.shift());` or `array.pop(arr.unshift());`

Comment: Halcyon, I have 2 applications the first is model turing machine with ticker tape and the second is a music player that jumps songs (forwards and backwards)... It's a simple piece of functionality and Im looking for a more elegant solution...

Comment: Hamms, well spotted, thank you. Removed and simplified.

Comment: Redu, interesting solution but the existing one is more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Use the modulus operator.

```
function loop (posChange, array) { array.lp = array.lp || 0; array.lp = (array.lp + posChange) % array.length; return array[array.lp]; }
```

Comment: That's good to know RK. The problem with this solution is that it has no 'memory' of the current tickertapeloop position.

Comment: This better? I added in an array.lp property to store the index of the tape.